# How can I call the send function without getting output?

Tags: python, scapy

Does anyone know how to send a packet using scapy and not receive any output?

This is the command:

```
send(packet, iface="eth0")
```

This is the output

```
Sent 1 packets.
```

I'm trying to get it not to print the packet count line at all.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try the `verbose` parameter. [Scapy documentation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/files/scapydoc.pdf) says that `verbose` should "make the function totally silent when 0". Both `False` and `0` appear to work. For example:

```
>>> send(IP(dst="1.2.3.4")/ICMP())
.
Sent 1 packets.
>>> send(IP(dst="1.2.3.4")/ICMP(), verbose=0)
>>> send(IP(dst="1.2.3.4")/ICMP(), verbose=False)
>>>
```

You can get little more information using `help()`:

```
>>> help(send)
Help on function send in module scapy.sendrecv:

send(x, inter=0, loop=0, count=None, verbose=None, realtime=None, *args, **kargs)
    Send packets at layer 3
    send(packets, [inter=0], [loop=0], [verbose=conf.verb]) -> None
(END)
```

Comment: In fact `False` is an alias for `0` FYI.